# Node Express API - Object Mapper

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

We have created a new Node JS API using Express Framework (Typescript as scripting language). This API internally calls an external API. In order to call the external API from within our API, we need to do a translation of the API models to External API Models. Are there any NPM Packages that are available which does the Object to Object mapper?

Comment: Use the Ramda lib and pickBy function with an array or object of keys from external API model you want to collect, the sample will be: `const external = R.pickBy(<key-in-that-array>, initial-model)`

Comment: I've just written a library to map js entity object <-> dto object, you can try it here https://github.com/sontx/mapstructjs. There is also a playground to test if it's suitable for your use case https://www.sontx.dev/mapstructjs/

Answer (score 1):

As i understood your problem i recommend this package which i really find usefull for typescript backends: class-transformer

the github link : https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#classtoclass

Also automapper-ts is a good choice too: https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper

i don't need to explain more than that i think. they have a good docs there. I hope it helps.

Comment: But this has the ability to convert a Json to Class object and vice versa. But is there some tool that can convert a object to object

Comment: Also it does have object to object they have `classToClass()`method i think that's what you are looking for  maybe i'm wrong https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#classtoclass